# CSS select very direct child

Tags: css

Is it possible to select the element `First` but not `Second`?

```
<p> <code>first</code> </p>
<p> Text <code>second</code> Text </p>
```

I intend to select `<code>` when its child of `<p>` but without content (except whitespace) in `<p>`

I want to do it without JS, if it is not possible that would also be an answer if its explained

Comment: I would say.. you need a combination of CSS and Javascript for this.. so idea is select all `p` tags which has a `code` tag as direct child and then filter the once in which the `text` property of the `p` tag is empty

Comment: those who are down 
voting, must comment the reason.

Comment: @VijayKumarB — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a filter in jQuery:

```
$('p').filter(function() {

  var nodetoCheck = $(this).contents()[0];
  if ($(this).contents()[0].nodeValue.trim() === '') {
    nodetoCheck = $(this).contents()[1];
  }

  if (nodetoCheck.nodeType === 1) {
    return true;
  }
}).addClass('selected');
```

JSfiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/eywk7b53/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
p:first-child > code {
  color:#fff;
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<p> <code>first</code> </p>
<p> Text <code>second</code> Text </p>
```

Also included fiddle code if you do it with jquery

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocs69ss5/7/)**

Comment: thanks, but I want to do it with css or I wont do it - styling with JS is dirty